# opening the detail view in searchdisplaycontroller

Tags: objective-c

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 44)];
    searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];

    searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

    [searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDataSource: self];
    [searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDelegate: self];![enter image description here][2]


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)] autorelease];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

    // inizializziamo l'oggetto Data
    _objects = [[Data alloc] init];

    filteredlist=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:_objects.lista ];
}
```

In this method I added so as to open the detail view

```
 [searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDataSource: self];
 [searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDelegate: self];
```

The only problem is that it opens the view for that cell, I instead need to open the detail view associated with that name in the list initially loaded.

The problem is to open the corresponding detail view when I do a search

When I do a search I have to open the detail view when I click on the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just update Tom's answer:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if (tableView == self.tableView) {
            // ...do your tableView stuff
        } else if (tableView == searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"detailViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
        }
    }
```

Comment: @FlinkDo not use the storyboard

Comment: does not work    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"detailViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

Comment: @user1949260 Because you should change DetailViewController to your DetailViewController name.

Comment: Did you change filename in initWithNibName:@".."?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what's you problem here but make sure that in your delegate selectors you check for the `tableView` parameter to distinguish your search result table view from your initial table view. E.g.:

```
[...]
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        // ...do your tableView stuff
    } else if (tableView == searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        id someSearchResultObject = [_filteredlist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        SomeDetailViewController *vc = [[SomeDetailViewController alloc] initWithSearchResult:someSearchResultObject];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
        [vc release];
    }
}
[...]
```

Comment: No, this has already been done.

The problem is to open the corresponding detail view when I do a search

Comment: @user1949260 Do you use xibs or storyboard?

Comment: Probably you should clarify your question. I don't have a clue what you mean by "open the corresponding detail view when I do a search".

Comment: When I do a search I have to open the detail view when I click on the name.